# Windows path including drive without colon

Tags: command-line

I compiled a unix program to a windows exe file using MinGW.
The issue is that the program parses arguments and changes the colon `:` into something else.
Is there a way to specify a windows path such as `C:\Path` without using the colon next to the drive letter ?

Comment: Where does the path go? If it's to a standard user area, such as user/app data/roaming you can use Environment Variables

Comment: You can use a Linux program as-is using WSL, although file-names look different than `C:\`.

Comment: Doesn't MinGW have a compat layer (like Cygwin does) that lets you use Unix-style paths?

Comment: What about using `set PROMPT` to change the command prompt? https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx Or did I not understand the question? $N$G should suffice no?

Comment: @grawity I am not running it in MinGW prompt (nor cigwin) so I don't know if I can use a unix style path with the program it compiled. If so, that might be the solution.

Comment: `set PROMPT` might work, what would be the new command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows Environment Variable, generically `%location%`

`C:` is `%HOMEDRIVE%` or `%SystemDrive%`

So, `C:\Path` becomes `%HOMEDRIVE%\Path`

Comment: The problem is that is I write that, it is first parsed and then `C:\Path` is sent to the program, not solving my original issue.

Comment: That's a real facepalm of a catch 22 there. The app automatically converts to using illegal characters...

Answer (score 0):

Try running that program inside C:\path folder so then it will be same directory
and thus no need for you to give a : sign

Comment: I have multiple TB of data to access scattered on many drives, it is impossible to use this approach. Otherwise I would have done it before.